# Multiple submit buttons with different value

Tags: java, forms, jsp, button, submit

I need to capture the value of the submit button but pressing the button only sends me the value of the first generated button.

This is my code

modificarVivienda.jsp:

```
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Codigo vivienda
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Direccion
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Numero
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Tipo vivienda
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Condominio
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Rut propietario
                    </td>
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${lstviviendas}" var="v">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ${v.cod_vivienda}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${v.direccion}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${v.numero}
                    </td>            
                    <td>
                        ${v.tipo_vivienda}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${v.nombre_condominio}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ${v.rut_propietario}
                    </td>
            <input type="text" value="${v.cod_vivienda}" name="cod_vivienda" hidden="true">
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Modificar" id="btnModificar">
            </td>
            </tr> 
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    int cod_vivienda = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cod_vivienda"));

    DAOVivienda dv = new DAOVivienda();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ArrayList<Vivienda> vivienda = dv.buscarPorId(cod_vivienda);
    session.setAttribute("viviendaAModificar", vivienda);
    response.sendRedirect("vivienda/modificar.jsp");
}
```

Comment: I fixed some grammar, but I still don't know if what you ask for is what you want to ask. I only see one submit button in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I need to capture the value of the *submit button*"

None of your *submit buttons* have a name, so no value is submitted *for the button*.

I think you meant to say that you want the value of the related `<input>` named `cod_vivienda`.

> "pressing the button only sends me the value of the first generated button"

That is not correct. All the `cod_vivienda` values are submitted. You probably just called [`getParameter("cod_vivienda")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)), and javadoc says:

> If you use this method with a multivalued parameter, the value returned is equal to the **first value** in the array returned by `getParameterValues`.

As you can see, to get all the values, you have to call [`getParameterValues("cod_vivienda")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)).

To actually get a single parameter named `cod_vivienda`, with the value matching the button pressed, you should use the `<button>` element, which can associate a value with the button, separate from the displayed text.

Replace:

```
<input type="text" value="${v.cod_vivienda}" name="cod_vivienda" hidden="true">
<td>
  <input type="submit" value="Modificar" id="btnModificar">
</td>
```

With:

```
<td>
  <button type="submit" name="cod_vivienda" value="${v.cod_vivienda}">Modificar</button>
</td>
```

Now, only the name/value pair of the button pressed will be submitted to the server.